# How can I test if a value lies within a Range?

Tags: rust

I'd like to be able to create a [`Range`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) and then test if a variable is contained in that range. Something that looks like this:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 3..5;
    assert!(a.contains(4));
}
```

Right now, the only obvious thing I see is to use [`Iterator::any`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.any). This is ugly because it would take an O(1) operation and make it O(n):

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 3..5;
    assert!(a.any(|v: i32| v == 4));
}
```

Comment: I have a crate (`range_check`) that provides `Contains` and `Within` traits for this.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As of Rust 1.35, the original code will *almost*<sup>1</sup> compile as-is using [`Range::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#method.contains):

```
fn main() {
    let a = 3..5;
    assert!(a.contains(&4));
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Passing `&4` instead of `4` to `contains()`.

Comment: Would it not make sense to have a method called `between(a, b)` that can be called on any num types? I do like your answer but Im not sure I like that I need to create `Range` first. My reason is very simple: Most IDEs will autocomplete `between`  method.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `match` too:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = 132;
    match v {
        1..=100 => println!("Inside"),
        _ => println!("Outside")
    }
}
```

Comment: According to rustc version 1.51.0 the ... (range pattern) is **deprected**. Use ..= (inclusive range) instead. See also [Tracking issue for exclusive range patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37854).

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html), which is similar to `match`:

```rust
if let 3..=5 = 4 {
    println!("Inside");
}
```

Also it is easy to assign to a variable:

```rust
let s = if let 3..=5 = 4 {
    "Inside"
} else {
    "Outside"
};
println!("{}", s);
```

Comment: Note that this only works for const ranges.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing on `Range` itself (at present, anyway), but it is not difficult to do this; after all, it just takes a couple of comparisons:

```
4 >= a.start && 4 < a.end
```

Comment: Do you think a PR to add this (to all the `Range*` structs) would be welcomed?

Comment: Not without an RFC. Frankly, nonessential feature expansion is unlikely before 1.0. That said, an RFC is relatively easy to write.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: @mkirk: what about negative numbers? If you’re using signed integers there’s nothing special about negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my crate [cond_utils](https://crates.io/crates/cond_utils) which allows you to write things like:

```
if number.between(0, 10) {
    println!("Number is between 0 and 10, limits excluded");
}
```

or:

```
if number.within(0, 10) {
    println!("Number is between 0 and 10, limits included");
}
```

It also has other range comparison methods, for left and right limits, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't technically answer your question, but if you want to test that a variable is between two other variables, you could use [`chain-cmp`](https://crates.io/crates/chain-cmp) crate:

```
use chain_cmp::chmp;

let n = 7;
assert!(chmp!(5 <= n < 10));
```

The nice thing about `chmp!` compared to a stand-alone `between` function is that you naturally see whether range ends are included or excluded.

Answer (score -1):

Before getting into question, you can manifest your code fancier a bit in this way.

```
fn main() {
    assert!((3..5).contains(&4));
}
```

Parentheses around 3..5 **must** used because `3..5.contains($4)` is same as `3..(5.contains($4))`.

Let's start with why we need `&` before `4` in `contains()` method.

`contains()` method take reference as parameter. You can find It in rust reference -- [`contains()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#method.contains) method in `Range` struct.

What that means is you are not taking ownership from the parameter of `contains()`. This method is used to check whether there is the item you are looking for, or not. Therefore, there is no reason for this method should take ownership of the item which is the parameter of `contains()`.

This is why you got compile error and this might be confused at first. Due to ownership and borrowing system of rust, when you are using some functions, you should always consider using literal with reference rather than just put value into the parameter of functions.