# Alternatives to matching floating point ranges

Tags: rust

What's the best way to write a series of floating point range comparisons?  To use the example from the GitHub comment below,

```
let color = match foo {
    0.0...0.1 => Color::Red,
    0.1...0.4 => Color::Yellow,
    0.4...0.8 => Color::Blue,
    _         => Color::Grey,
};
```

The naive solution would be a painful if-else chain:

```
let color = {
    if 0.0 <= foo && foo < 0.1 {
        Color::Red
    }
    else if 0.1 <= foo && foo < 0.4 {
        Color::Yellow
    }
    else if 0.4 <= foo && foo < 0.8 {
        Color:: Blue
    }
    else {
        Color::Grey
    }
}
```

Is that really the best option available?  There must be a nicer way to write this, right?

---

Related to [Alternatives to matching floating points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875142/alternatives-to-matching-floating-points), but this is for range comparisons.

Originally mentioned in [the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41620#issuecomment-303333591) for `illegal_floating_point_literal_pattern`, and something I'm running into constantly.

Comment: If your ranges are all contiguous, omitting the lower bound keeps things pretty readable: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=02d45de79815a37567cfdd59bd07ca18&version=stable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would personally do this:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Color {
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Blue,
    Grey,
}

trait InRange {
    fn in_range(self, begin: Self, end: Self) -> bool;
}

impl InRange for f32 {
    fn in_range(self, begin: f32, end: f32) -> bool {
        self >= begin && self < end
    }
}

impl From<f32> for Color {
    fn from(f: f32) -> Color {
        match f {
            x if x.in_range(0.0, 0.1) => Color::Red,
            x if x.in_range(0.1, 0.4) => Color::Yellow,
            x if x.in_range(0.4, 0.8) => Color::Blue,
            _ => Color::Grey,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Color::from(0.2), Color::Yellow);
}
```

Comment: Nice idea.  I'm assuming that should be `impl InRange for f32`?

Comment: even better: `impl<T: PartialOrd> InRange for T { ... }`!

Comment: @couchand: Pedantically, that would be logically invalid, as `PartialOrd` doesn't guarantee that ranges even make sense in the first place.  The constraint you want there is `Ord`, but that would exclude floats due to NaN.  IEEE Floating Point: because we can't have nice things.

Comment: Could you explain why you are dereferencing `self` in the implementation of `InRange` for `f32`?

Comment: @KomronAripov The numeric operators are only implemented for `f32` and `f32` or `&f32` and `&f32`. Try to remove the dereference operator, and you'll see that the snippet doesn't compile anymore.

Answer (score 15):

Since Rust 1.35, the `InRange` functionality [implemented by Boiethios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037357/3650362) is already provided in the [`contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#method.contains) method on `Range<f32>`:

```
impl From<f32> for Color {
    fn from(f: f32) -> Color {
        match f {
            x if (0.0..0.1).contains(&x) => Color::Red,
            x if (0.1..0.4).contains(&x) => Color::Yellow,
            x if (0.4..0.8).contains(&x) => Color::Blue,
            _ => Color::Grey,
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would tend to write this with only one comparison against each number, which reduces the chance of typos introducing bugs:

```
impl From<f32> for Color {
    fn from(f: f32) -> Color {
        match f {
            x if x < 0.0 => Color::Grey;
            x if x < 0.1 => Color::Red,
            x if x < 0.4 => Color::Yellow,
            x if x < 0.8 => Color::Blue,
            _ => Color::Grey,
        }
    }
}
```

This style also makes it more obvious that there are two disjoint ranges that return `Color::Grey`: `x < 0.0` and `x >= 0.8`.

### See also

- [How can I test if a value lies within a Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265036/how-can-i-test-if-a-value-lies-within-a-range)