# I want to use the condition of the match statement in Rust to do "0..=a+5"

Tags: rust

I would like to use Rust's `match` statement to process variables differently when they are in an arbitrary range and in other cases. In that case, the code would look like this:

```rust
// idx is usize variable
// num is usize variabel

let res: Option<f64> = match idx {
    1..=num-5 => {
        Some(func())
    },
    _ => None,
};
```

But I receive an error:

```
error: expected one of `::`, `=>`, `if`, or `|`, found `-`
  --> src/features.rs:34:22
   |
34 |         1..=num-5 => Some(func()),
   |            ^ expected one of `::`, `=>`, `if`, or `|`
```

Comment: Uhm, seems like the compiler is not actually getting it. Btw, this is just available as an experimental feature.

Comment: Remove the comma after `Some(func())` in your updated example.

Comment: The error in your update doesn't go with the code you added to the post. I've reverted that edit because it doesn't seem to add anything to the original question. If you have problems implementing the solution in an answer, consider asking in the comments below the answer or asking a new question -- editing the question should be used to respond to comments, adding clarification or details about the original question.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [Alternatives to matching floating point ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49037111/3650362).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the dynamic range over a match guard:

```rust
fn main() {
    let idx = 6;
    let num = 15;
    let res = match idx {
        n if (1..=num - 5).contains(&n) => Some("foo"),
        _ => None,
    };
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46232cc2d33459822bee7a063746f0d3)

Answer (score 1):

Runtime values cannot be referenced in patterns. Also you cannot make operations.

Use const instead

```
const num :i32 = 19 - 5;

let res: Option<f64> = match idx {
    1..=num => {
        Some(func())
    },
    _ => None,
};
```

Comment: The answer is ok. But I don't think it really applies. I guess num would variate over runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I modified it as in the Update section and received more errors.